# FullCalendar inserts 1.5 hours on renderEvent

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

When I call my FullCalendar like so:

```
   dayCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
     {
    title: "Scheduled Callback",
    start: callbackDate,                            
    allDay: false
     },
     true // make the event "stick"
   );
```

it sticks in an event with a duration of 1.5 hours even though I haven't set an end date/time.
How do I ensure it sets an event with no duration or an event for just 30 minutes.
My calendar is set to show events in blocks of 30 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `defaultEventMinutes` option in your setup for full calendar just set this option to `30`.

[Documentation is here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/defaultEventMinutes/)

I hope this helps!